# How to calculate this integral without any integration techniques?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> Differentiate  $f(x) = (5x+2)\ln(2x+1)$ with respect to $x$. Hence, find $\int \ln(2x+1)^3dx$.

Because of the word "Hence" I'm assuming that the question doesn't allow integration techniques such as integration by parts or substitution.

The first part is trivial. The derivative is $5\ln(2x+1) + \dfrac{2(5x+2)}{2x+1}$. Now my line of thought so far has been to somehow get this derivative to the desired result: $\ln(2x+1)^3$ and then use $f(x)$ to get the integral. However I don't see any straight way to do this.

So I decided to experiment a little. Firstly I differentiated $(3x+2)\ln(2x+1)$ and got $$3\ln(2x+1) + \dfrac{2(3x+2)}{2x+1}$$ Now at least I have the $\ln(2x+1)^3$ term but I have another complication: $\dfrac{2(3x+2)}{2x+1}$.

I decided to take a look at the answer: $3x\ln(2x+1) + \dfrac{3}{2}\ln(2x+1) - 3x + C$. I thought that if I differentiated this, I would have some idea of where I should go, and how to proceed. So that's what I did, and I got:
$$3\ln(2x+1) + \dfrac{2(3x)}{2x+1} + \dfrac{3}{2x+1} - 3$$ This is perfect because $\dfrac{2(3x)}{2x+1} + \dfrac{3}{2x+1} - 3$ cancels out perfectly. But I have no idea how to get here, starting from $f'(x)$. But I'd say that my first experiment was pretty close. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you must integrate by parts

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner it must be possible without integration by parts because it's a problem from a textbook which does not include integration techniques.

Comment: @TheOddbodNumber for $ln(2x+1)^3$, you actually mean $ln((2x+1)^3)=3ln(2x+1)$?

Comment: @Bubububu yes $(2x+1)^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative is

$$f'(x) = 5 \log{(2 x+1)} + \frac{10 x+4}{2 x+1} = 5 \log{(2 x+1)} + 5 - \frac1{2 x+1} $$

Integrate both sides wrt $x$:

$$f(x) = (5 x+2) \log{(2 x+1)} = 5 \int \log{(2 x+1)} dx + 5 x - \frac12 \log{(2 x+1)} +C$$

Thus

$$ 5 \int \log{(2 x+1)} dx = \left (5 x + \frac52 \right ) \log{(2 x+1)} - 5 x + C$$

or

$$\int \log{(2 x+1)^3} dx = \frac32 (2 x+1) \log{(2 x+1)}- 3 x + C'$$

Comment: In line 2 did you mean $5x$ instead of $x$?

Comment: @TheOddbodNumber: yes, thanks.

Comment: Ah ok, so that's how you get rid of $\dfrac{10x+4}{2x+1}$... I used a similar idea in my answer, but with a different equation. I should've noticed this earlier. Thanks!

Comment: I think in the last line it should be $2x$ instead of $6x$

Answer (score 0):

Alright so from my first experiment we have the derivatie $3\ln(2x+1) + \dfrac{2(3x+2)}{2x+1}$. To get this to just $3\ln(2x+1)$ we subtract $3$ and $\dfrac{1}{2x+1}$. This gives us the expression $$\bigg(3\ln(2x+1) + \dfrac{6x}{2x+1} + \dfrac{4}{2x+1} \bigg) - 3 - \dfrac{1}{2x+1}$$ Integrating gives us $(3x+2)\ln(2x+1) - 3x  - \dfrac{1}{2}\ln(2x+1) + C$

Answer (score 0):

You have:

$$f'(x)=5ln(2x+1) + \frac{10x+4}{2x+1}$$

$$3ln(2x+1)=\frac 3 5(f'(x)-\frac{10x+4}{2x+1})$$

You can simply integrate both sides, it doesnt require by parts.

Comment: How do you evaluate $\int \dfrac{10x + 4}{2x+1}$?

Comment: @TheOddbodNumber $\frac{10x+4}{2x+1}=5 - \frac 1{2x+1}$, then you can substitute $u=2x+1$